# Go to parent activity without it being started

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to implement a "go back" to root activity function.

I have on my ActionBar set

```
setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And in my manifest I have set

```
<activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="@string/title_activity2"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity1">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Activity1"/>
</activity>
```

And if I start the app to Activity1 and start Activity2 the back arrow in upper left corner appears and takes me back to Activity1.

The problem is that through a notification I can start Activity2 directly and when I try to use the back button I just end up on my home screen.

So I searched on the issue and found (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Where it said to implement in the onOptionsItemSelected

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    Log.d("Writing Activity","OnOptionsItemSelected entered");
    int id = item.getItemId();
    boolean handled = true;
    Log.d("Writing Activity","OnOptionsItemSelected id: "+id);
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_save:
            saveFile();
            break;
        case R.id.action_delete:
            deleteFile();
            break;
        case R.id.action_help:
            help();
            break;
        case R.id.up:
        case R.id.home:

            Log.d("Writing Activity","OnOptionsItemSelected Home");
            Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
                Log.d("Writing Activity","OnOptionsItemSelected 1");
                // This activity is NOT part of this app's task, so create a new task
                // when navigating up, with a synthesized back stack.
                TaskStackBuilder.create(this)
                        // Add all of this activity's parents to the back stack
                        .addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent)
                                // Navigate up to the closest parent
                        .startActivities();
            } else {
                Log.d("Writing Activity","OnOptionsItemSelected 2");
                // This activity is part of this app's task, so simply
                // navigate up to the logical parent activity.
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
            }
            break;
        default:
            Log.d("Writing Activity","OnOptionsItemSelected default");
            handled = super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    return handled;
}
```

And it seemed logical for me but it didnt work out.

Is there something that I missed?

Update: I logged the method and it seems that it doesnt enter the case R.id.home at all and goes to the default statement. but when i catch the ID of the item selected I get 16908332 which corresponds to home...? –

Comment: Add debug logging and see which of the `if...else` clauses is being executed when you start Activity2 from a notification and then press UP.

Comment: Ok this is wierd. I logged it and it seems that it doesnt enter the case R.id.home at all and goes to the default statement. but when i catch the ID of the item selected I get 16908332  which corresponds to home...?

Comment: post the complete `onOptionsItemSelected()` method.

Comment: updated the main issue. Tried to add up as well before I found the ID value

Comment: Sorry, I've not got any other ideas at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems like the real answer to the above problem is that the switch case is not it because I'm using R.id.home instead of android.R.id.home.

If I change to that it hits the switch and the job can continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok not exactly an answer to the problem but a solution that make it work the way I want it to.

Instead of routing it directly to Activity2 from a notification I start up Activity1 and with a extra parameter in the intent start Activity2 before the setContentView method is called.
This makes it look like it started directly to Activity2.

Then I also had to remove the extra intent parameters. 
If I didnt to this then the old intent will stay and be rerun if I later open the app again from the app history.